# Корректная работа сайта HTML на всех устройствах

Tags: html

Означает ли этот код что сайт будет работать корректно только на платформе IOS?

```
<link href="css/ios.css"
```

Comment: этот сайт нигде не будет корректно работать, потому что использует некорректный синтаксис

Comment: Как мне можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, в Вашем случае правильно будет написать следующим образом:

`<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/ios.css">`

А во-вторых, это значит только то, что к Вашему проекту подключится файл стилей с названием **ios.css**. И будет это корректно отображаться или нет зависит только от того, какие стили Вы пропишете в этом файле.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133844/discussion-on-answer-by-stark----html---).